# Set Rewrite Rule for Azure CDN Static App

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-cdn

I have a azure static app that has URL path https://azureurl/$web/filename.json to provide access to read a json file.

Instead, I would like to be able to read the json file with this URL https://customdomain/filename.json without the /$web in the path.

I have tried to both redirect and rewrite the CDN endpoint using the Rules Engine but not getting very far.  Based on what I read, I would prefer doing this using rewrite to keep on the server side.

I have the custom domain setup correctly and I'm using Azure CDN.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Hi @mrbenson, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   When you are deploying a CDN profile for Azure Front Door using Static Web App, you must provide an **‘Origin Host name’** and `origin type` as **static web app**. At that point, when you create a CDN profile for the static web app, a CDN profile gets created with a WAF policy. Thus, I would suggest you `configure the CDN profile with your custom DNS records so that you will be able to configure your CDN profile and its endpoint` accordingly.

To find more information regarding the above for **creating a CNAME DNS record and add a custom domain to your CDN endpoint**, refer to the below documentation link: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns%2Cazure-portal%2Cazure-portal-cleanup#add-a-custom-domain-to-your-cdn-endpoint

•   Also, you will have to **integrate your static web app with your CDN profile** so that you would like to be able to **read the json file with custom domain URL**. For that purpose, you will have to `integrate static website with Azure CDN and enable Azure CDN for your static website`. Thus, to do so, kindly refer to the documentation URL below for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/static-website-content-delivery-network

Once done, you should be able to `access the json file with the custom domain CDN URL by storing the JSON file in the storage account and hosting the static website in that storage account itself which will make it easy for you to configure the same with CDN profile`.